# What does the point data in topic velodyne_points represents and how can we use this data in custom program for getting depth of objects?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with VLP_16 and want to use it in my custom program. I want to know what does velodyne_points publishes and how can i use it my program for depth estimation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233062/what-does-the-point-data-in-topic-velodyne_points-represents-and-how-can-we-use-this-data-in-custom-program-for-getting-depth-of-objects?/) by [rechie26](https://answers.ros.org/users/21687/rechie26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2016-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume the velodyne_points topic you are talking about is coming from the Velodyne driver.
This publishes PointCloud2 data. If you use the rostopic tool, you can see the data format to understand it better.
Essentially, it is an array of "x, y, z, intensity, laser number" points. So if you are trying to determine depth, you would need to play with algorithms on this 3D point cloud output.

---

Originally posted by [ecegrad](https://answers.ros.org/users/2582/ecegrad/) with karma: 26 on 2016-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1